# Superclass parameterized by one type cannot be instantiated by subclass that specifies a subtype

Tags: java, generics

Not sure of a good way to word this: If I have a generic `SuperClass<T>` and a subclass that explicitly parameterizes the superclass (i.e. `SubClass extends SuperClass<SubParameter>`, why can't the subclass be used to instantiate an instance of the superclass that's parameterized with a superclass of the parameter the subclass uses (i.e. `SuperClass<SuperParameter> = SubClass<SubParameter>`).

#### Example

Since that was a mess of sub/super class, here's an example:

I have a generic class `Block` parameterized by types that extend class `Shape`. I then make a subclass `SquareBlock extends Block` that explicitly specifies the type parameter of its superclass. That type parameter is a subclass of the expected type parameter in the superclass (`Square extends Shape`).

**Question:** Why can't an instance of `SquareBlock` be used in a variable of type `Block<Shape>`, since both `SquareBlock extends Block` and `Square extends Shape` are true?

```
// outer class
class Block <T extends Shape> {}
class SquareBlock extends Block<Square> {}

// inner class used in type of outer class
class Shape {}
class Square extends Shape {}

public class Generics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Square class can be used where Shape class is specified
        Shape shape = new Square(); // works  
    
        List<Shape> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Square()); // works 
             
        Block<Shape> block = new SquareBlock();
        // Type mismatch: cannot convert from SquareBlock to Block<Shape>
    }
}
```

Comment: A `SquareBlock` is a `Block<Square>`, not a `Block<Shape>`, as the duplicate explains.

Comment: Wow yeah that does explain it. Thanks, I hadn't found that question.